# How to speed up dict find task in numba?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, numba

I have a python function, and want to speed up it with numba. The most time consuming part is a search of tuple in a set/dict. Can anyone give an idea how to solve this?

```
idNeg = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], ..., [7,8,9]])
validSet = {(1,2,3):True, (5,4,3):True, ..., (2,5,3):True}
@jit
def CalcNeg(idNeg, validSet):
    l = len(idNeg)
    for j in xrange(l):
        corplc = np.random.choice([0, 2])
        idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, VE.shape[0])
        while validSet.has_key((idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2])):
            idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, VE.shape[0])
    return idNeg
```

I tried like this, but the speed not change compared the code without `@jit`.

Comment: the speed did not change.. compared to what?

Comment: The builtin check should be very fast. Try `key in validSet` but it should be the same thing. Using a nested `dict` and checking for the existence of one tuple element at a time might help, but only if hashing the latter elements is quite slow.

Comment: why would you need to check all three of `(idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2])` if only one if them changes? couldn't you do `if validSet.has_key((idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2]): continue ; while idNeg[j, corplc] in validSet:...`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Compared with the code without `@jit`

Comment: @AlexHall I tried key in validSet, but it seems numba didn't support that. What do you mean by nested dict?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, because the valiidSet is a dict of tuple. A tuple stand for a relation, so I should check the tuple in the dict.

Comment: Something with a structure like `{ idNeg[j, 0]: { idNeg[j, 1] : { idNeg[j, 2] } } }` (the innermost level being just a set).

Comment: "The most time consuming part is a search of tuple in a set/dict" ... Out of curiosity, how did you determine this?  dictionary lookup should be quite quick, though the hashing of the tuple each time _might_ be slowing you down a bit...

Comment: Numba does not generically speed-up arbitrary python code. It only supports a small subset of the language and you only get big gains if Numba can compile the whole function in `nopython` mode (see the docs). If you provide example inputs, I could possibly help you optimize this in numba.

Comment: Hi, @JoshAdel, I have edited the question and added some sample data. Could you help me to find a way for numba to speed up it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% clear on the exact nature of the desired inputs (contents or typical shapes), but the key to getting good performance gains in Numba is to be able to jit a function in `nopython` mode (as opposed to python object mode). The original function used data structures, specifically a dict, which is not supported currently.

Again, I don't know the exact use case or whether the following modification is valid, but I took the `validSet` dict and converted it's keys to a real set object where the value in the key, value pair was `True`.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import random

# Original function
def CalcNeg(idNeg, validSet, N):
    l = len(idNeg)
    for j in xrange(l):
        corplc = np.random.choice([0, 2])
        idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, N)
        while validSet.has_key((idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2])):
            idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, N)
    return idNeg

# Modified version, compiled in nopython mode (njit)
@nb.njit
def CalcNeg2(idNeg, validSet, N):
    l = len(idNeg)
    c = np.array([0,2])
    for j in xrange(l):
        corplc = np.random.choice(c)
        idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, N)
        #while validSet.has_key((idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2])):
        while (idNeg[j, 0], idNeg[j, 1], idNeg[j, 2]) in validSet:
            idNeg[j, corplc] = random.randrange(0, N)
    return idNeg

# Some test data
N = 40
M = 2000
idNeg = np.random.random_integers(0, N, size=(M,3))
tmp = np.random.random_integers(0, N, size=(M,3))
validSet = {tuple(tmp[k,:]): True for k in xrange(tmp.shape[0])}

# convert validSet to real python set for keys with value == True
_validSet = {k for k,v in validSet.iteritems() if v is True}
```

And now some timings from an ipython notebook using the `%timeit` magic:

```
%timeit CalcNeg(idNeg, validSet, N)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.84 ms per loop

%timeit CalcNeg2(idNeg, _validSet, N)
1000 loops, best of 3: 444 µs per loop
```

So on my machine that's an 18x speed-up. I'm using Numba 0.25. Just as a note, switching to a set in the original python function gives a small difference, but more like a 25% speed-up.

If the test data is unrealistic, or if the transformation of the dict to a set is not appropriate, let me know. Without more specifics, it's hard to tell how to approach the problem.

Comment: Hi, @JoshAdel, Thanks for your answer. But after I run the code, it said:Failed at object (object mode backend)
Internal error:
NotImplementedError: Unknown operator 'in'. Which version of numba do you use? I use 0.19.1

Comment: @maple as noted in the answer, I'm using the latest version of Numba, 0.25. Numba is under very active development and each release typically adds support for a lot of new python and numpy features as well as improvements in compilation speed, and general performance. More than any other package, I highly recommend using close to the newest release.